# Exporting video with RGBA just won't work

Tags: transparency, video

I used to be able to export .mov files with transparency using this setting:
*FFMPEG Video > Container QuickTime > QT rle/Qt Animation > Color RGBA + Render > Film > Transparent*.

Now  I am using blender 3.5 and it just won't work no matter what. Whenever  I export with this method  I try placing the .mov in Blender Video Editor and keep getting a video with solid black background.

I as well tried exporting separate .png sequence and making a video out of it with the same export setting using Blender Video Editor and it keeps coming out black.

I have applied the same method before and it used to work, I searched everywhere and still can't find a solution to fix this.

Comment: 1) are you sure you have a "visible" transparent area in your render? If you set your viewport in render shading, you should be able to see the transparency checkerboard where your environment would be without the Film Transparent option. 2) in the VSE, is your strip blend option set to Alpha Over in the sidebar?